yarn install failing with "Integrity check failed ...", but checksums and hashes are correct
When I run yarn install on my project, I get:
$ yarn install
yarn install v1.22.22
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/d3-color/-/d3-color-3.1.0.tgz: Integrity check failed for "d3-color" (computed integrity doesn't match our records, got "sha512-zg/chbXyeBtMQ1LbD/WSoW2DpC3I0mpmPdW+ynRTj/x2DAWYrIY7qeZIHidozwV24m4iavr15lNwIwLxRmOxhA== sha1-OVsoM9+scVB/EqwvevI7+BneJOI=")

yarn cache clean and rm -rf node_modules has been run before. In my yarn.lock file, the hashes and integrity values are correct:
"d3-color@1 - 3":
  version "3.1.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/d3-color/-/d3-color-3.1.0.tgz#6594da178ded6c7c3842f3cc0ac84b156f12f2d4"
  integrity "sha1-OVsoM9+scVB/EqwvevI7+BneJOI= sha512-zg/chbXyeBtMQ1LbD/WSoW2DpC3I0mpmPdW+ynRTj/x2DAWYrIY7qeZIHidozwV24m4iavr15lNwIwLxRmOxhA=="

If I run
yarn install --update-checksums
yarn install

it installs fine. However I don't want the checksums updated on every build. They should be static.
The --update-checksums switch does nothing to the yarn.lock file:
$ git status
HEAD detached at 13cc87725
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ yarn install --update-checksums
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @***/react-library@1.33.0" has incorrect peer dependency "i18next@^23.4.5".
warning " > @***/react-library@1.33.0" has incorrect peer dependency "react-i18next@^13.2.0".
warning "@***/react-library > react-dom@18.3.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^18.3.1".
warning "i18next-scanner > acorn-dynamic-import@4.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "acorn@^6.0.0".
warning "@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli > @nestjs/axios@0.0.8" has incorrect peer dependency "@nestjs/common@^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0".
warning " > service-worker-loader@4.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
$ husky install
husky - Git hooks installed
Done in 136.48s.
$ yarn install
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
$ husky install
husky - Git hooks installed
Done in 0.73s.
$ git status
HEAD detached at 13cc87725
nothing to commit, working tree clean

What am I missing here?
@fengelhardt we use gitlab as custom registry for our private packages. Public packages come from npmjs / registry.yarnpkg.com. This is the .npmrc in use:
@<private-namespace>:registry=https://<gitlab url>/api/v4/projects/24549/packages/npm/
//<gitlab url>/api/v4/projects/24549/packages/npm/:_authToken=<gitlab personal access token>

@Allan Wind we don't exactly know which hashes yarn compares, but we tried all different possibilities in the yarn.lock file:

integrity "sha1..."
integrity "sha512"
integrity "sha1... sha512"
integrity "sha512... sha1"

Nothing worked.

Do you use custom registries? Any registry that forks a source can mutate the hash. If it's 1:1 not sure about hash matches but the registry may affect the hash even if the repo checksum is the same. (that would need verification). Look under npmrc yarnrc dot files. Either in the repo or in home dir. Repost those registries (maybe make them abstract) if not npm or artifactory. Do not include your Auth though!

If I read that error message correct you have a sha1 hash and comparing against a remote sha256 hash which are obviously different.

Have you tried yarn set version 1.22.22?

I don't know if @ works in the question but you would need to @AllanWind in a comment for me see it.  I was referring to sha512-zg/chbXy... and I imagine yard generates the lock file for you (I never used yard). abdurrehman's answer looks promising.  Good job on revising the question with new data.

@D.lola Why would make any difference?  Op is already using yard 1.22.22 per output.  I am genuinely curious.

@AllanWind making sure the same yarn version is used across all environments (repo , local, CI/CD, etc.). mismatched versions might handle integrity differently.

I see that you deleted node_modules, I believe it can help if you also delete yarn.lock and only then re-install.
Try this:
yarn cache clean
rm -rf node_modules yarn.lock
yarn install


Did that already multiple times to no effect.

I ran into the same issue with Yarn, where I kept getting the "Integrity check failed" error, even though the checksums and hashes in my yarn.lock file were correct. After trying a bunch of things, this finally solved the problem for me:
Force Yarn to use networkConcurrency=1:
It turns out that when you're fetching packages from multiple registries (like npm and a private GitLab registry, in my case), parallel downloads can mess with checksum verification. By setting the network concurrency to 1, you make Yarn download packages sequentially, which can avoid race conditions and checksum mismatches.
Just add this line to your .yarnrc file:
networkConcurrency 1

This fixed the issue for me, and I haven’t seen the integrity error since. Hopefully, it helps you too!

Thanks for the input, but it didn't help. I tried setting networkConcurrency 1 in my .yarnrc file and yarn install --network-concurrency 1, but I still get the same error.

You can try with adding this to ~/.yarnrc
unsafe-disable-integrity-migration false

Clean cache
yarn cache clean

and re install
yarn install

From here

unsafe-disable-integrity-migration false. Setting this to false will
enable the yarn.lock checksum migration (enabling sha512 support).
Causes lockfile format change. This will be the default starting from
version 2.0.

Reference to the issue and solution here
